# Linux mint can't focus on window after click on app on taskbar

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gnome

In linux mint mate 17.2 when a window is active and i click on another app on taskbar, I should again click on app to gain focus.

For example chrome is active window and i click on atom editor on taskbar to bring it on. When i start typing, nothing will be written because atom isn't active yet and i should click on atom title bar to activate it.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer.

By enabling an options here:

`Control Center > Window Preferences > Behavior (tab) > Select windows when the mouse moves over them`.